# How to set additional question properties with Limesurvey API?

Tags: api, limesurvey

I still have issues in my project to fully automatize a survey creation process.

Thanks to this [post](https://www.limesurvey.org/forum/installation-a-update-issues/102270-how-to-fetch-additional-question-properties-by-json-remotecontrol-api), I managed to **get** additional question properties.

But now, I would like to **set** additional properties.
I tried the same syntax, just replacing `aQuestionSettings` param in get_question_properties with `aQuestionData` in set_question_properties.

Is it possible do this with Limesurvey API ?

Comment: Let's see if I can get our API expert to answer these questions for you.

Comment: I finally decided to automatize the survey creation process by creating from scratch a LSS/XML file that I import with the API call `import_survey`. But I am still interested in this issue !